# java.lang.SecurityException: Signers of org.bouncycastle.util.Encodable

Tags: java, java-8, jar, token

I have the next class:

```
public class PruebaFirmaUtils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            
            String token = "token";
            String pwdKeyStore = "password";
            
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, pwdKeyStore.toCharArray());
            Certificate[] chain = (Certificate[]) keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);
            
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) chain[0];
            
            CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(token.getBytes());
            List<X509Certificate> certList = Arrays.asList(cert);
            
            Store<?> certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
            
            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            ContentSigner sha256Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(key);
            
            ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
            v.add(getSigningCertificateV2(cert, "SHA-256", true));
            
            AttributeTable signedAtributtesTable = new AttributeTable(v);
            signedAtributtesTable.toASN1EncodableVector();
            
            gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                    new SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder (new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build())
                            .setSignedAttributeGenerator(new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(signedAtributtesTable))
                            .build(sha256Signer, new X509CertificateHolder(cert.getEncoded())));

            gen.addCertificates(certs);

            CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, false);
            
            System.out.println(sigData.getEncoded());
            
            
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperatorCreationException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CMSException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    private static Attribute getSigningCertificateV2(final X509Certificate cert, final String digestAlgorithmName, 
            final boolean doNotIncludePolicyOnSignigCertificate) {
        
        SigningCertificate scv = null;
        
        try {
            final GeneralName gn = new GeneralName(X500Name.getInstance(cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getEncoded()));
            final GeneralNames gns = new GeneralNames(gn);
            
            final IssuerSerial isuerSerial = new IssuerSerial(gns, cert.getSerialNumber());
            
            final byte[] certHash = MessageDigest.getInstance(digestAlgorithmName).digest(cert.getEncoded());
            final ESSCertID essCertID = new ESSCertID(certHash, isuerSerial);
            
            
            final PolicyInformation[] polInfo = doNotIncludePolicyOnSignigCertificate ? null : getPolicyInformation(cert);
            
            if(polInfo != null && polInfo.length > 0) {
                final ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
                v.add(new DERSequence(essCertID));
                v.add(new DERSequence(polInfo));
                scv = SigningCertificate.getInstance(new DERSequence(new DERSequence(polInfo)));
            } else {
                scv = new SigningCertificate(essCertID);
            }
            
                    
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signingCertificateV2, new DERSet(scv));
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static PolicyInformation[] getPolicyInformation(final X509Certificate cert) {
        if(cert == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El certificado no puede ser nulo");
        }
        
        final byte[] certificatePoliciesBytes = cert.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.32");
        if(certificatePoliciesBytes == null || certificatePoliciesBytes.length < 1) {
            return new PolicyInformation[0];
        }
        
        return (CertificatePolicies.getInstance(
                ASN1Sequence.getInstance(
                        ASN1OctetString.getInstance(
                                certificatePoliciesBytes).getOctets())))
                .getPolicyInformation();
    }

}
```

When executed it gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Signers of
> 'org.bouncycastle.util.Encodable' do not match signers of other
> classes in package at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.checkPackageSigners(ClassLoader.java:454) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:379) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:360) at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:730) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:96) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1187) at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:739)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:605) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:937) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:882) at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:343) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:865) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)

I use the next libraries:

> -bcmail-jdk15on-1.49
>
> -bcpkix-jdk15on-1.52
>
> -bcprov-jdk15on-1.52
>
> -org.opensmarthouse.core.io.jetty.certificate-0.10.1

I have used other versions but following failing. You may not have found the right one.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks.